# Fill missing values in a column with the trend of previous values

Tags: r, data.table, na, fill

I am looking for a function that fills my NA values in a data.table column with a "trend" of the previous values.
I know that there is the function: na.locf()
But this function only uses the last available value and forwards it into the future.
What I want is that the specific function looks a the "trend", so at the evolution of more than just the last available values und writes this trend into the future.

```
data
year,V1
2020,1
2021,1.5
2023,2
2024,2.5
2025,3
2026,NA
2027,NA
2028,NA
2029,NA
2030,NA


expected output:
data
year,V1
2020,1
2021,1.5
2023,2
2024,2.5
2025,3
2026,3.5
2027,4
2028,4.5
2029,5
2030,5.5
```

Related but not a duplicate of these posts:

- [How to replace NA (missing values) in a data frame with neighbouring values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252546/how-to-replace-na-missing-values-in-a-data-frame-with-neighbouring-values)
- [Filling NA using linear regression in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634504/filling-na-using-linear-regression-in-r)

Comment: Do you always want a linear interpolation?  What happens when the trend is _not_ linear?  You also might want to include a larger data set which includes multiple gaps.

Comment: Not a duplicate of linked question, @zx8754 please read both

Comment: @jangorecki re-opened.

Comment: No, I do not necessarily need to have a linear interpolation. What I am looking for are multiple ways also in a mathematical sense how to decrease a value based on previous evolution.

Comment: "multiple ways" - the question is becoming too broad to be answerable, be more specific, what is the expected output for your example data. From existing example data, the trend is only positive, increasing at 0.5 per row.

Comment: What is needed is to define how far in the past you want to look to project interpolation. For example na.locf looks only for single value in the past.

Comment: You may want to look into topic of time series data forecasting because you are precisely asking for that AFAIU.

Comment: It would be great if I do have a function that would look 3 time steps in the past and follow this trend for future values.

Comment: Sounds like a linear regression over previous 3 values. I would try something like  `some_lm_fun(shift(V1, 1:3))`.